Step-by-step guide to linking gnuplot to Octave within Virtual Studio Code (VSC)
I am aware of a number of previous questions (here, here and here for example) pointing out to the need to modify a file named .octaverc.
Now, there are different files with that name (here). In Windows 11 and Octave 8.3.0 keeps two files in here:

I tried opening them with Notepad, and inserting the phrase graphics_toolkit("gnuplot") at the end, but I haven't been able to later save the file in any form due to lack of admin privileges even in my own laptop at home and logging in as admin (going to cmd line and setting up an admin profile just for this with net user administrator /active:yes).
Unfortunately, the extensions for Octave in VSC do not have too many preference options to link to gnuplot.
I am not sure how to set up a new .octaverc file in the working directory. Would it be for each folder? Would it be a text file? Would I find the wd from inside VSC? Would it also have to have the . of hidden file in the name? Would it bear an extension, such as .txt?
So I am lost and wasting a ton of time on an issue that is probably easy to solve with some more detailed steps.

For other dummies out there like me... What follows fixed the issue:
I created a blank text file with Notepad within the folder where I keep my Octave and Matlab files (file.m). So I didn't go to Program Files, where Octave executable files and gnuplot are.
The file is simple as can be:

I saved it by choosing Save As File > All Files so that it wouldn't have an extension. And, yes, with the .octaverc as though it was a Linux hidden file. Here it is among some random files in VSC:


Now, in the extension Octave Execution LucasFA the PATH to Octave needs to be included:

For completeness the other pertinent extensions I have installed are GNU Octave WASM, Octave Formatting, Octave Debug and Octave Degugger. For gnuplot I have the extensions Gnuplot by mammothb and Gnuplot by Mario Schwalbe, as well as Gnuplot Preview by fizzybreezy.
